# Display preloader while page fully loads jquery3

Tags: jquery

i feel like i'm crazy.

Most basic preloader isnt working in jquery 3.xx

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $(".preloader-wrap").fadeOut("slow");;
});
```

Preloader wont fade/will stay on screen forever.
And i was googling for one hour and cant find jquery3 alternative, all threads about preloader are from like 10 years ago.

How can i please achieve preloader that waits till page is fully loaded and then fades away?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.load`](https://api.jquery.com/load/) is an ajax function.

You're looking to add an event listener for the `load` event:

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
    $(".preloader-wrap").fadeOut("slow");
});
```